# Universal apps and Kinect V2

Tags: wpf, unity-game-engine, windows-10, win-universal-app, kinect-sdk

In my work we are preparing for developing a fitness application that is supposed to run on Windows 10 (Maybe windows 8.1) and XBox One. We want to use the Kinect V2 for measuring the performance of the user while doing a workout.

I have a few questions:

1: Is it possible to develop a Windows 10 Universal App, that uses the Kinect V2 for both Windows 10 PC and XBox One - so one codebase for both products? I have read somewhere that Kinect V2 SDK is not supported for the Universal Windows Platform, but i can not understand why i should not be supported?

2: If its not possible to target the Universal Windows Platform, do we then need to target Windows 8.1 Store Apps, and develop a version for both Desktop and XBox One?

3: We want to show a fitness video that runs in the background, with a UI on top/overlay that displays the users vitals like heart-rate, intensesnes level, repetitions, and calorie burned. Can we use WPF/XAML for this, or do we need to hire a developer that excels in Unity or XNA?

4: If we hire a Unity/XNA developer, are these technologeis compatible with the Kinect V2?

Comment: Next time it would be better if you seperate different questions in different questions. In this case (1) and (2) could be one question and (3) and (4) another.

Comment: The scope of the question is way too broad, and for your first question i think you can develop windows 10 app that uses kinect check out this http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/08/01/running-kinect-for-windows-applications-on-windows-10-things-you-should-verify/

Comment: This question is too broad and better suited for gamedev.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

This is a multi-part question but the individual parts that are relevant to you should be easy enough to answer: Kinect 2.0 works with Windows 10 development, but not currently supporting the Windows 10 UAP. Target the Windows 8.1 UAP and your app will still work on Windows 10 (and potentially Xbox One if you have access to the Xbox One dev kit, which you can only get right now through signup).

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/kinect/faq

And, your question 3, yes, you can interact with the Kinect data using only the C#/XAML pipeline. You shouldn't need a Unity developer for this interaction. I did a tutorial video explaining how to get the data and if you download the Kinect SDK there are C# sample codes.  https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Amanda-Lange/Kinect-100-August-2015

Comment: Update to this - Xbox One Dev Kit mode is now available - http://www.polygon.com/2016/3/30/11318568/xbox-one-dev-kit